# Feeds for suitable questions from other sites in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Could perhaps adding feeds from hsm-related questions from other Stack Exchange sites into chat be useful? I could, for example, imagine [ho.history-overview tag](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ho.history-overview) from MathOverflow, [math-history tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-history) from Mathematics, [history tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) from Physics. (And other users might have different suggestions.)

I thought that this might be useful since it might bring attention of hsm users to other questions which might interest them. You can notice that something similar exists, for example, in the [main chatroom on Academia site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2496/the-ivory-tower?tab=feeds).

---

Also if this is deemed as something useful, another question is whether to use [the main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/18230) or whether to create a separate room which would serve basically for this feeds and for discussions related to posts from this feeds.

I am bringing up the possibility of separate chatroom mainly to avoid possibility that feeds will create most of posts in the main room, as previously discussed here: [Is the xkcd feed in the chat really necessary?](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271)

Comment: There is also the [history-of-science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-science) tag on Earth Science.